# Express response is not defined when using separate callback

Tags: node.js, express, mongojs

Just an elementary question.

The following code return tasks successfully:

```
const mongojs = require('mongojs');

const db = mongojs('localhost:27017/tasks', ['tasks']);

router.get('/tasks', function(req, res, next) {
    db.tasks.find(function(err, tasks) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        if (tasks) {
            res.json(tasks);
        }
    });
});
```

But, when I split it and call it as callback, it returns: **References: tasks is not defined.**

Repository.js:

```
const mongojs = require('mongojs');

const db = mongojs('localhost:27017/tasks', ['tasks']);

module.exports = {
    ReadAllTasks(callback) {
        db.tasks.find(function(err, tasks) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err, null);
            }
            callback(null, tasks);
        });
    }
}
```

Route.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const repository = require('./repository');

router.get('/tasks', function(req, res, next) {
    repository.ReadAllTasks(function(err, tasks) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        if (tasks) {
            res.json(tasks);
        }
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

Anyone know to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try this, because you are not returning the valid object.

```
module.exports = {
    ReadAllTasks: (callback)=>{
        db.tasks.find(function(err, tasks) {
            if (err) {
                callback(err, null);
            }
            callback(null, tasks);
        });
    }
}
```